# Is stealing a cookie any different to stealing a refresh token?

Tags: identityserver4

I'm currently working on authentication and authorisation with Angular and .NET Core. From what I've read on various posts on SO and from the IdentityServer and Auth0 docs is that a refresh token should not be used with a SPA - I understand the reasons why, no explanation needed here.

What I don't understand is why stealing a refresh token is any different to stealing a cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some options (*SameSite*, *HttpOnly*) supported by browsers making stealing a cookie hard to perform. Tokens stored in a browser do not have such protection for today. Briefly that's it. You can find deeper comparison [here](https://leastprivilege.com/2019/01/18/an-alternative-way-to-secure-spas-with-asp-net-core-openid-connect-oauth-2-0-and-proxykit/)